# CSS class with nested elements

Tags: html, css, class, responsive

I want to display table elements as blocks only in a specific class without using a class on every single sub-element of the table.

What I've tried:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 650px)
{
  .contactform 
  {
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
      display: block;
   }
}
```

```html
<table class="contactform">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label> First Name </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label> Last Name </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label> E-Mail </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label> Phone </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. Also, CSS without any HTML it is supposed to apply to, tells us rather little. Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue.

Comment: why are you using tables if you want to force them to not be like table anymore! use another tag like ```div``` or ```section``` instead, your media queries are wrong, ```min-device-width``` and ```max-device-width``` are deprecated you should use ```viewport meta``` instead of them and just use regular ```min-width``` and ```max-width``` in your css, beside, your media queries are also wrong in another way, you have wrote media for both under 768 and above 768! therefore the media will be always applied to your element

Comment: Just made an edit, hope it could clarify my question, sorry but i'm not really used with coding..

Comment: You can't have media queries within a CSS rule.

Comment: You can't nest CSS selectors without a pre-processor ([yet](https://caniuse.com/css-nesting)). But you [might be able to use `:is()`](https://caniuse.com/css-matches-pseudo), but that's not going to get you much. Just write out the selectors: `table.contactform, .contactform thead, .contactform tbody, .contactform tr, .contactform td, .contactform th {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid using a class on every single 'sub-element' within the table you can use the `:is()` pseudo class to target certain descendants within your given class.

One issue is that by default the browser styles table elements... as a table. So you might have to flip your media query around

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .contactform,
  .contactform :is(table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr) {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="contactform">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label> First Name </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label> Last Name </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label> E-Mail </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label> Phone </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Or for best [browser compatibility](https://caniuse.com/css-matches-pseudo):

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .contactform,
  .contactform table,
  .contactform thead,
  .contactform tbody,
  .contactform th,
  .contactform td,
  .contactform tr {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<table class="contactform">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label> First Name </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label> Last Name </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <label> E-Mail </label>
    </td>
    <td>
      <label> Phone </label>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This makes the `<label>` elements and any other elements inside the table inline as well. If the OP had block elements in there, they'd lose that styling. Using asterisk is like dropping a nuclear weapon when you want to swat a fly. Just type out the six selectors.

Comment: @HereticMonkey What's funny is that I actually started with :is() and moved to * thinking it was a simpler solution.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have retracted my nukes, please reconsider yours